# Can someone find me a reference to this quote?

Tags: development

I'm looking for a reasonable reference to a known software personality who said something along the lines "make sure your software runs the most common cases fast/easy but all cases are possible".  I'm sure there are many 80/20 quotes, so I'm looking for the most famous that gets that point across.

-Robot

Dear Mods: Don;t you think a quote by Larry Wall regarding programming meets the criteria?  You're harsh!

Comment: Questions on Super User should be about computer software or hardware. Even if it is related to programming, a "quote" is not software, nor hardware.

Comment: @Robot:  @Gnoupi is right; this question is off-topic, try a different site such as answers.yahoo.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like the Larry Wall quote about his Perl programming language, that it should "make easy things easy and hard things possible".